removing item from list of list is removing entire list not just item
I'm trying to remove value "0" from my list of list
a subset of that list is:
[([29.7589382, -95.3676974], '0', '0', '0'), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106], '0', '0', '0'), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217], '0', '0', '0'), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518]

so I expect the result to be
[([29.7589382, -95.3676974]), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106]), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217]), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518]

But instead it's removing the entire list instead of just "0"
I have tried the following:
for p in listConverted[:]:
    if "0" in p:
     listConverted.remove(p)

and
result = [[elem for elem in inner_list if elem != "0"] for inner_list in listConverted]
print(result)

which give me:
[[[30.2943681, -87.5735935], [38.7604815, -92.5617875], [32.3293809, -83.1137366],

basically removing all the lists that have it instead of just item in the list
I have also tried doing a nested for loop for this. I removed the code but the logic was something like:
for x in list
 for i in x:
   if "0" in i:
     remove i

which basically complained "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list". Which from what I understand means it did not find the value.
I might be missing something obvious or misunderstanding something but I can't seem to figure out what this is. Please point me to the obvious thing that I'm missing.
Thanks

You don't have a list of lists. You have a list of tuples (notice the parens). Tuples cannot be mutated. Your listConverted.remove(p) is removing the entire tuple from the outer list. You'll have to create a new list containing new tuples that are derived from the original.

Try using the pprint function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) to get a better understanding of your data structure.

@KurtisRader Thanks for making me realize it was actually a tuple and pointing me to pprint. It was really helpful!

Does this help?
data = [([29.7589382, -95.3676974], '0', '0', '0'), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106], '0', '0', '0'), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217], '0', '0', '0'), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518])]

result = [tuple(filter(lambda x: x != '0', sublist)) for sublist in data]

print(result)

>>> [([29.7589382, -95.3676974],), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106],), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217],), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518])]

It prints an extra null value for tuples of size one. If that null is a problem, you could add an extra if statement for tuples of length one.

As the comment said, you're not having a list of list, but list of tuples. In order to get from what you have to your desired output, you can use a list comprehension:
>>> stuff = [([29.7589382, -95.3676974], '0', '0', '0'), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106], '0', '0', '0'), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217], '0', '0', '0'), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518])]

>>> [tuple([z for z in x if z != '0']) for x in stuff]
[([29.7589382, -95.3676974],), ([45.4208777, -75.6901106],), ([30.5254797, -91.0899217],), ([38.980666, -76.9369189], [36.0998131, -80.2440518])]

Since tuples are immutable, you have to rebuild them from the items that you want (excluding the ones you don't). Since you have only one value in your tuples (the list of two floats), the trailing comma is needed to distinguish those as tuples.
